# "Feed action request limit reached" - Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, error-handling

I am getting this error from the Facebook SDK. Please help me to solve this problem, if possible.

> "Uncaught OAuthException: (#341) Feed action request limit reached
>   thrown in..."

Comment: `"Feed action request limit reached"` means that you have been posting too many things to peoples profiles... There are limits on friend requests also.  Not much can be done about this.  You might want to consider simply posting less items.

Comment: is there any way to increase this limit ? or can catch this exception ?

Comment: Please specify what SDK you are using...

Answer (score 1):

You can not increase the limit enforced by Facebook.  Even though in some cases many posts to users profiles might be a desirable outcome, sometimes it is considered spammy; Facebook prevents this by enforcing limits on things like this.

If you simply want to catch this error and display a more subtle error message your users, you can wrap your calls to Facebook with a `try {} catch` block.

You have not specified the language you are using so I'll give an example in PHP -

```
$post_obj = array(
  'link' => 'www.stackoverflow.com',
  'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
));

try{
  $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',$post_obj);
  if (!$ret_obj) {
    throw new Exception('Post unsuccessful!');
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Display some error to the user.
}
// If we reached here we know that the post was successful.
```